# For loop over a function to get function output in R

Tags: r

I want to compute the integral of a function associated with each value in a vector. Using an example, I precisely describe my aim as follows.

Suppose `x` and `y` are independent random variables, and `I` is an indicator variables such that `I=1` if `y > 0.25x` or `zero` otherwise. I want to make `n` draws of y from an exponential distribution, and for each draw I wish to compute the integral of `g = xf(x)I` over the distribution of `x`, `f(x)`. I want this distribution to be exponential with parameter value of 1. I tried the following code in `r`.

```
f = function(n){
  h = list()
  g = numeric()
  y = rexp(n)
  for(i in 1:n){
    h[i] = function(x){(x * dexp(x) * (y[i] > 0.5*x))}
    g[i] = integrate(h[i], lower=-Inf, upper=Inf)
  }
  return(summary(g))
}
```

But then when I run f(3) I get an error message "`*Error in h[i] = function(x) { : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'"*`. But when I run the following codes

```
y = rexp(1)
h = function(x){x * dexp(x) * (y > 0.5*x)}
integrate(h, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf)
f(3)
```

I get results. Does somebody has suggestion on how to improve this code so that `h` function is evaluated at each values of `y` with the output being a `function`, which then will be passed to the `g` function?

Comment: Try using `[[` to index your list rather than `[`, ie `h[[i]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `sapply` instead of the loop:

```
f = function(n){
  y = rexp(n)
  g = sapply(1:n, function(i) 
                  integrate(function(x) (x * dexp(x) * (y[i] > 0.5*x)), lower=-Inf, upper=Inf))
  return(summary(g))
}
```

Comment: Why would you suggest using `sapply` - I'm not saying it's an incorrect suggestion, but a reason would be nice.

Comment: I used `summary(g[1,])` to extract the value of the integral since g is a list. The use of `sapply` makes sense because it calls for a specified function (`h` in this case) for each element in a vector `y`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `[[` to subset `h` rather than `[`. This is because `[` will return a sub-list rather than the contents. Also `integrate` returns a complex structure, if you just want the value, append with `$value` to pick that out.

```
f = function(n){
  h = list()
  g = numeric()
  y = rexp(n)
  for(i in 1:n){
    h[[i]] = function(x){(x * dexp(x) * (y[i] > 0.5*x))}
    g[i] = integrate(h[[i]], lower=-Inf, upper=Inf)$value
  }
  return(summary(g))
}

f(3)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.2456  0.3269  0.4082  0.4069  0.4876  0.5669
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. `sapply` also does a similar job as @Thilo suggests.